# Can Size of the Angular-Strap's "Aside" window reduced or increased?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am using Angular-Strap's Aside. Works well! But wanted to know whether the size of the "Aside window can be decreased. If so, how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either override the existing placements (`left`/`top`) with CSS, overriding the styles from [bootstrap-additions.css](https://github.com/mgcrea/bootstrap-additions/blob/master/src/aside/aside.less) that are used in the docs:

`.aside.left {
  min-width: 200px;
}`

Or you could use the `placement` with a new custom one (eg. `narrow-right`) using this CSS:

`.aside.narrow-left {
  min-width: 200px;
}`